# How to delete records of a table when its primary key is referred as secondary key in another table?

Tags: sql

How to delete records of a table when its primary key is referred as a foreign key in another table in a single query?

Comment: Please do some research. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You cant unless the FK is nullable, in that case you could null the FK in the other table and then delete in the PK table. Its called Data-Integrity and was probably created with a purpose in mind - like "without this data, that other data makes no sense ..."

Answer (score 0):

DELETE *
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON 
table1.(Primary key column name) =table2.(Foreign key column name);

try this

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.